# In how far does the Whitney trick work in the piecewise linear setting in $\Bbb R^4$?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-complexes, embeddings

I usually read about the [Whitney trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) in the context of smooth manifolds, but I wonder in how far it works in the piecewise linear (PL) category as well. I have a specific setting in mind that I will describe below, but a more general answer is welcome too.

In my setting I have two 2-dimensional PL-surfaces $X_1, X_2$ embedded in $\Bbb R^4$ (think of embedded simplicial complexes). Let's say they intersect in points $x_1,x_2\in X_1\cap X_2$ of opposite sign, so that theoretically they can "annihilate" each other. I also have two internally disjoint paths $\gamma_i:[0,1]\to X_i,i\in\{1,2\}$ with $\gamma_i(0)=x_1$ and $\gamma_i(1)=x_2$ as well as a *Whitney disc* $W\subset\Bbb R^4$, that is, a 2-disc with boundary $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2$ that is otherwise disjoint from $X_1\cup X_2$.

> **Question:** What do I need to assume to perform the Whitney trick, that is, to "pull $X_1$  across $X_2$" (guided along $W$) to get rid of both intersections?

The following is my biggest worry:

- at the moment, my two curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ might pass through vertices of the triangulated surfaces at which the surfaces are not necessarily [locally flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_flatness).

There are other situations that I would be interested to know more about:

- what if the Whitney disc $W$ is itself not locally flat at some internal vertex? (this is secondary, as it is not the case in my setting).

Comment: Failure of local flatness is codimension 2, so just wiggle the paths and they don't pass through such points. (You didn't ask, but what if $x_i$ are not locally flat? Then the intersections can't be transverse and I don't think you can define an intersection index. Anyhow, wiggle the surfaces and the intersections points will be locally flat.) If an interior point of the Whitney disk is not locally flat, I think you're in trouble. The only place dimension 4 comes in is that a disk in high dimension is automatically flat.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your comment. "[...] wiggle the paths and they don't pass through such points." But I then also need to wiggle the Whitney disc and it is not apparent to me that it stay internally disjoint from the surfaces. Or is this somehow clear? I can't really visualize what trouble awaits me when I play in the neighborhood of a not-locally-flat point.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^4$ admits a smooth structure, by the Whitney immersion theorem, one can approximate the map of surfaces by immersions. So we may get around with the local flatness problem but at the cost of creating more (self)-intersections. Under certain situations, one can add more Whitney disks to get ride of those new intersections.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming that the paths came first and you could fix them before creating the disk, but of course you can't create Whitney disks in 4d. I think that you can move the disk along the wiggle, but I'm not sure. A surface is a cone on a circle. A non-locally flat point is a cone on a knotted circle. Wiggling the path means moving towards an arc in the circle. I think that you can straighten that arc, leaving all the knotting in the complementary arc and move the disk along, but I'm not sure.